# IBM DevOps Pipeline: How to Access Artifacts from Previous Job?

Tags: build, build-process, ibm-cloud, devops, build-pipeline

I have a build stage as shown below with two build jobs, a `frontend` and a `backend` job. How do I directly access the *Build Archive Directory* of the `frontend` job from the `backend` job's build script?

I need to access the `frontend` build artifacts in order to properly build the final archive. And I can see all the artifacts show up in the Artifacts tab for the `frontend` build. But how do I access that from the second job, i.e. `backend` build?

I saw [here](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/deploy/#jobs) that there is an Environment variable to access the *current* job's archive dir, but I need to access the other jobs archive dir.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, both jobs inside a stage are run in complete separate environments.  They do not have access to the artifacts of the other jobs in the stage.  The way to get around this is to create a new stage for the 'backend' job, and then set the input for that stage to be the build artifacts from the 'frontend' job

Comment: Yeah that's what I did. I was also considering issuing a `curl` command from the second job (i.e. `https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@hub.jazz.net/pipeline/<username>/<projectName>/<stageUUID>/<jobUUID>/latest?download=all`) and fetching the artifacts from the first job that way. Do you think that would work?

Comment: @david - You should be able to use curl to get the artifacts, although, I have not done it myself.  This is the url you will want to hit: `https://hub.jazz.net/pipeline/<username/<projectName>/download/<stageId>/<jobId>/latest`

Comment: Do you have any updated info for IBM BlueMix? Jazz is not available anymore.