# IBM Bluemix DevOps pipeline - Is there an environment variable to retrieve the current stage id

Tags: environment-variables, ibm-cloud, devops, build-pipeline

Having a look at the comments at the bottom of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100405/ibm-devops-pipeline-how-to-access-artifacts-from-previous-job), it seems that it is possible to use curl to download the artifacts produced by a build job.

Indeed, I could successfully grab the output of a build job by calling a url like: https://hub.jazz.net/pipeline/username/projectName/download/stageId/jobId‌/latest

The jobId in the url above corresponds to the env variable IDS_JOB_ID, which is available inside a pipeline stage.

But now, I am looking for an env variable that contains the stageId.
Is there such an env variable available inside the Bluemix devops pipeline?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no environment variable for the stage id.  You can grab the stage id for a stage from the url of the stage configuration page.  Note: the IDS_JOB_ID that is available is for the current job that is running.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes I noticed that the stageId could be grabbed from the url of the stage config or log/history page. But I was looking for a way to do this dynamically inside a job. If there is no such env variable in the pipeline, I am afraid I won't be able to do what I want then :-(

Comment: If this function is something that you need, consider adding the request to the Bluemix Ideas site at the following URL: https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas